# How to filter birthday only by day and month and between X days?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Given a table `User` with id, name and birth_date, I want to filter all the users that will celebrate their birthday within X days from today ignoring the year.

For example, if today is November, 24, I want to get all the users that celebrate their birthdays from November 24 to 27, despite their birth year.

```
LocalDate today = ZonedDateTime.now().toLocalDate();
LocalDate endDay = today.plusDays(3);

-------------------------------------
filter from today to endDay

1 | User A | 11/24/1995
2 | User B | 09/02/2000
3 | User C | 11/26/1998
4 | User D | 11/25/2005
```

In this case I'd like to get users A, C and D.

I'm trying to do this using Java JPA @Query annotation, but if there is a way to do it in PostgreSQL would also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [date_part](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_part/) function for this, however the math gets fuzzy if the time period you want crosses over into the next month or the next year.

If you do it by checking month and date you will need:

1. a query for when the period fits in the current month
2. a query for when the period fits into two months.

If you do it by checking by day of year (doy) instead, then you have to worry about shifting to the next year, but also whether the date being checked against is in a leap year, whether the date you are looking for is after the leap day, and also if in your application you are getting the post-leap day.

Finally you can use direct string comparison by formatting it like this `to_char(birth_date, 'MM-DD')`. And again you will need two queries for when your last dates cross into the next year. The `between` check is inclusive.

```
... where to_char(birth_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '11-28' AND '12-01'


... where to_char(birth_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '12-29' AND '12-31'
OR to_char(birth_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '01-02'
```